# Сообственное действие по клику на UITabBarItem вместо показа ViewController'a

Tags: ios

Здравствуйте!

Стоит задача - по клику на элемент в таб баре показывать `PopOver`'om `ViewController`. 
Каким способом можно обмануть стандартное поведение, чтобы вместо показа вкладки по клику на элемент таб бара оставалась старая вкладка и выполнялось мое действие, в данном случае показ pop-over?

Готов предоставить любую нужную информацию.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно переопределить метод [didSelectItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarDelegate) у [UITabBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

определить тот ли элемент был выбран (для этого можно использовать поле [tag](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem), так как [UITabBarItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) прямой наследник [UIBarItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem)) и уже после этого делать что душе угодно.

Comment: но лучше так не делать. по сути, это неправильное желание. если возникает необходимость в таком действии, то в проекте потенциально или проблемы с проектированием дизайна или с пониманием Apple HIG.

Comment: К тому же зарежектят если планируете выставлять в аппстор, так как такое переопределение стандартных элементов не допускается в HIG. Лучше найдите для этой цели более подходящий контрол

Comment: Ну что же, хоть это и не было решением, но ответ натолкнул меня на мысль. 

Вместо UITabBarDelegate я использовал метод UITabBarControllerDelegate - shouldSelectViewController

Он позволяет сделать return NO; и новая вкладка просто не покажется. Тут же инстанциируется нужный класс, вычисляется координата показа. 

К сожалению, лимита текста на комментарий не хватает дабы привести решение полностью.
Всем спасибо, коллеги!